# How can I dynamically render both javascript data and html within the same angular curly braces ({{ }})?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am rendering different kinds of attributes within the same html element in the following manner:

Javascript:

```
var dataAttribute = {
    value:function(){ return 1;}
}
var listAttribute = {
    value:function(){ return "<div>My Arbitrary HTML
                                   <div>1</div>
                                   <div>2</div>
                                   <div>3</div>
                              </div>";}
}
var attributes = [dataAttribute,listAttribute]
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="attribute in attributes"> {{ attribute.value() }} </div>
```

How do I get the html in the listAttribute to render as HTML and not as text, while still retaining the ability to render the normal data of the dataAttribute?

Comment: why exactly you want to do such madness? create a directive instead of your `listAttribute` thing. Check out `ng-switch` directive.

Comment: you can try ng-bind-html, but not sure it works that way - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: @vittore this 'madness' is to allow attributes to provide their own return values via the common interface of value(). The html I will be rendering will most likely be a simple directive (ex: '<my-directive></my-directive>'). Above is a simplified example. I am dynamically rendering 10+ different models using the same template, and that template needs to account for different compositions of attributes and attribute types. I am open to suggestions on better architecture. I just don't want to manually code 10 different tables when I can do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just should not. Use `ng-switch` directive if you want to render different things based on properties of items in your collection. ( in worst case use series of ng-if inside your ng-repeat)

Do not invent another templating engine if you already using angular, you are just confusing yourself.

Little more explanation here. You already have code that generates that html somewhere. It really better by angular directives.

```
 <div ng-repeat="attribute in attributes" ng-switch="attribute.type"> 
   <div ng-switch-default> {{ attribute.value() }} </div>
   <div ng-switch-when="table"><my-table data='attribute.value()'></my-table></div>
   <div ng-switch-when="list"><my-list data='attribute.value()'></my-list></div>
</div>
```

And set of directives

```
 .directive('myTable', myTable).directive('myList', myList)
```

will hold all the logic to produce html from the data.

I.E. don't mix layout and data in one structure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a combination of @vittore and @YOU's answers:

Javascript:

```
var dataAttribute = {
    value:function(){ return 1;},
    type:'data'
}
var listAttribute = {
    value:function(){ return "<list-directive></list-directive>";},
    type:'list'
}
var attributes = [dataAttribute,listAttribute]
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="attribute in attributes" ng-switch="attribute.type"> 
    <div ng-switch-default> {{ attribute.value() }} </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="list" ng-bind-html="attribute.value()"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You better off still avoid that ng-bind-html here. How do you generate that html? move that to directives, then each ng-switch would be `<div ng-switch-when="list"><my-list data='attribute'><my-list></div>`